# Pulling ASP.NET MVC source from live site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I recently lost my source code to an ASP.NET MVC website, and all I have left is the live site. I was wondering if it's possible to get the original source of a site from the live site. I know it's possible for static sites using the `wget` utility, but it would mess up my site.

Comment: How did you deploy the website?  build+deploy or just copy everything?  Can you get to the filesystem on the live site or only via http/browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and poking my server, I sadly found it wasn't possible. I could still pull it off a server using `wget`, but that would result in a static style HTML site (which isn't what I want).